# IntegrityError and NOT NULL constraint failed Like and Dislike Functionality

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I'm trying to add like and dislike functionality to my application. I know there are lots of references I've checked them I was trying by myself. I've managed to add like and dislike in the database I've failed to retrieve and also I cannot redirect the same page. Please check my code and help me how to solve this issue.

I want to redirect to the `post_detail` page. I checked that I'm failed to add `count_likes` values to the `Post model`

***Ok, I'm trying again and again I made changes only one problem is remaining.
I want now to stay on the same page and same position. Is it possible please tell me how can I do that?***

### PostLike Model

```
class PostLike(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("user", "post")
```

### HTML page

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('likebutton').submit()" >
     <div class="ui labeled button" tabindex="0">
          <div class="ui red button comment">
              <i class="heart icon"></i> Like
          </div>
         <a class="ui basic red left pointing label"> {{ count_like | intcomma}} </a>
    </div>
 </a>

<form id="likebutton" action="{% url 'like_or_dislike_post' single_post.slug %}" method="POST">
       {% csrf_token %}
   <input type="hidden">
</form>
```

### Urls.py file

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('category/<slug:category_slug>/<slug:post_slug>', views.post_detail , name="post_detail"),
    path('like_post/<slug:post_slug>', views.like_or_dislike_post, name="like_or_dislike_post"),
]
```

### Views.py file

```
def like_or_dislike_post(request, post_slug):
if request.method == 'POST':
    each_post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=post_slug)

    try:
        liked_post = PostLike.objects.filter(user = request.user, post = each_post)
        if liked_post:
            liked_post.delete()
        else:
            PostLike.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user, post=each_post)

    except Exception as e:
        raise e

return render(request, 'pages/single_post.html')
```

### Error Image

[image]

Comment: When I like or dislike It's giving the above image shown error all I want to stay on that page also the same position like if I like I don't want to redirect to the same page on top position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def like_or_dislike_post(request, post_slug):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=post_slug)
        PostLike.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user, post=post)
        return render(request, 'pages/single_post.html')
```

If you want to have dislike, you can just do

```
PostLike.objects.filter(user=request.user, post=post).delete()
```

Then in `single_post.html` you better just count how much likes in DB, but not store it in separate field:

```
 {{single_post.likes.count | intcomma}}
```

But before you need to add related_name to Post:

```
class PostLike(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='likes')  # <- this allow to count likes like post_instance.likes.count()
```

Comment: Ok, when I try to add related_name='likes' it gave me an error like some sort of the same name so I removed the likes field from the Post model. I started directly count the likes fetched to my post detail page. Now the problem is cannot render or redirect to my post detail page or the same page it redirecting to (like/post_slug) like the URL I gave in the urls.py file. All I want now to stay on the same page and same position. Is it possible please tell how can I do that.

Comment: I've updated the post again please check the error image

Comment: `action="{% url 'like_or_dislike_post' post_slug=single_post.slug %}"` - try this change in your template